# PHP - can a long string of HTML be wrapped in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, variables

Can this be done - opening a variable with one PHP tag, then closing the PHP tag but keeping the variable open so everything beneath becomes the value of the variable? Or is there a limit on PHP variable size / characters?

```
<?php $content = " ?>

a bunch of content goes here <br />
with lots of HTML tags and JS scripts

<?php "; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your code would do is to store a string starting with `?>` and ending with `<?php` in the variable `$content`. That's probably not what you want to do? If you later echo such a string, you would most probably get errors due to these php tags.

As mentioned in other answers, heredoc would be a solution but in general you should try to avoid such situations where you have to store very long html sequences in a variable. Rather use a view file and inject some dynamic content there or use some sort of include.

So, depending on what you really want to do,your options are:

1. heredoc
2. `$content = "<html>markup here</html>";`
3. via output buffering
4. using a view (look for info about the MVC pattern, you can also just do VC for a start)
5. using includes

Comment: 1 and 3 could work. I want to avoid 2. Could you point me to a good tutorial on using a view?

Comment: CodeIgniter is a very good and light framework if you're getting started with MVC.

Answer (score 10):

You can either use [HEREDOC](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)/[NOWDOC](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
$content = <<< 'HTML'

a bunch of content goes here <br />
with lots of HTML tags and JS scripts

HTML;
```

or [output buffering](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), e.g.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

foo

<?php
    $var = ob_get_clean();
    var_dump($var); // will contain foo and surrounding whitespace
```

Answer (score 7):

No, but you can probably do some of it with [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$content = <<< END
some content here<br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hi');
</script>

END;
```

Comment: Might want to remove the space between `<<<` and `END` on the first line

Comment: @MichaelThompson although the examples on php.net and some syntax checkers I've seen indicate this, PHP doesn't mind spaces there: https://3v4l.org/k414A

Answer (score 3):

Read bout HEREDOC syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2):

`$content = 'large amount of text';`


or

`$content = 'text';

$content .= 'other text';

$content .= 'end text';`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?php ob_start (); ?>

.... html

<? 
$content = ob_get_clean (); 
?>
```

See http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php for details

Comment: this works, but in most cases it's better to use the HEREDOC method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

A closing tag inside double quotes as : `" ?>"` will not be treated specially. They are just string contents.

> is there a limit on PHP variable size / characters?

No. You can stuff as much as you can into a variable till your memory is full.

Comment: that's taking the code literal, but I don't think it's what the OP wants to do, is it?